# How do you increase the plugin timeout in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

Tonight, while my computer was devoting most of its CPU to other tasks, Chrome decided that every tab that was using a plugin had crashed.

In Firefox there's a configuration setting for the number of seconds that a plugin is allowed to be unresponsive before the tab is considered "crashed", but I haven't been able to find the analogous setting in Chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: Doubt Google would ever do something like that. Just goes to show you, even on a computer you have to let go before it's pried out of your cold, dead, RAM.

Answer (score 2):

There is not currently a way to do this because Chrome’s mission is to provide a minimal interface by doing things correctly so that users don’t have to configure options or make choices. (Of course when it doesn’t do things correctly, preventing the user from setting an option to fix it is annoying.)

I’ve submitted [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76230) to request a way to set the timeout, but like digitxp said, chances are that they won’t implement it (unfortunately, they have a tendency to think that their choices are always the right ones).

Comment: Chrome's "my way or the high way" is getting really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows**

1. Right-click the shortcut that you use to open Chrome, and select
   Properties from the pop-up menu.
2. In the Google Chrome Properties
   dialog, click the Shortcut tab and append the following value in the
   Target field:
   `--disable-hang-monitor`

   **Note: When you append the value in the Target field, ensure that you add a space between chrome.exe and `--disable-hang-monitor`**

**Mac OS**

1. Open Terminal.
2. Launch Chrome from the Terminal by appending the `--disable-hang-monitor` value as follows:

   `open –a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-hang-monitor`

---

source: https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/error-plug-unresponsive-google-chrome.html